# Is there an extension/eslint for ARIA attributes?

Tags: reactjs, accessibility, wai-aria

I'm trying to make my apps more accessible, and I was wondering if there's an extension or config in eslint that tells me where/what ARIA attributes I should use in my code. I tried a VSCODE extension called Web Accessibility, but I don't think it works with React.

Glad if anyone could help.

Comment: Try this https://www.npmjs.com/package/eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y

Comment: Gonna check that out. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was wondering if there's an extension or config in eslint that tells me where/what ARIA attributes I should use in my code.

There isn't. WAI-ARIA is complicated and there isn't a plugin that can tell you when to use it, which one to use and which is correct. That's like asking if there is a plugin that tells you when to use HTML.

Also, accessibility !== ARIA. You can have a perfectly accessible website and not having to write a single ARIA attribute. In fact, if you are not proficent in ARIA, you can make the website much worse, accessibility wise. Take it from someone who once **audited a website where web dev department used `aria-label` for every single link.**

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I know that accessibility encompasses many other things like colors, contrasts, font size, etc. It's just that ARIA is a little more complex to understand. I know there's a number of extensions that we can use to "audit" the website. Do you recommend any or should I avoid them too?

Comment: @ViniciusBortoletto, for auditing websites, the automatic extensions can help, but they shouldn't be only ones used - manual auditing should always accompany them. My favorite is Google Lighthouse, but many people love Accessibility Insights and axe.